# Archive of 3.5E characters?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I'm trying to write some software to generate characters for 3.5E. Is there a library of characters known to be correct with respect to RAW that I can download? Such a library would help me figure out where my algorithm is working correctly and where it is not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PCGen](http://pcgen.org/) is a fairly robust tool for generating 3.5e characters. While it is not a repository of pre-gens, the tool has a fair amount of peer review by a decent sized group of users such that you can be reasonably sure that characters created by it are acceptably close to correct. And since it is free, it has a very low cost to implement (other than the requirement for Java).

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of any limitations such as not implementing or ignoring certain classes, or other rules? Though, judging by the screenshot it looks pretty comprehensive.

Comment: It complies with the Open Gaming License requirements, so there will be a significant amount of material that is not represented (due to copyright reasons). But, aside from that, it should have more than enough source material to build a wide enough variety of PCs for detailed testing. So, if you are looking for a very specific build, it might not have what you need, but if you are simply looking for a wide variety, it should have you covered.

Answer (score 3):

I’m about 90% sure that this does not exist.

Actually, no, I’m about 100% sure the specific type of library you request doesn’t exist—because “known to be correct with respect to RAW” isn’t really a plausible standard. While you could probably—with extreme care—produce a character that avoids any and all RAW ambiguities, this would drastically reduce the data space, as so much of 3.5e involves some ambiguities. As a result, it is *vanishingly* unlikely that anyone would bother making such a library, and even they did, it probably wouldn’t actually be all that useful to you.

What I’m 90% sure about is that I don’t think there’s any substantial online digital “library” of characters that exists in a plausibly-scrapeable form.